# wordpress bootstrap slider carousel

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I hope someone can help me on this, been searching the web for an answer.
I use http://320press.com/wpbs/ for my wordpress in localhost but it seems that the carousel is not working properly.

Actrually I have to questions but the important part is the first one.

1. How can I make the carousel call a specific category instead of displaying all post inside my wordpress
2. You need to click the arrow so that the image slide will work, is there a way to set it to automatically slide?

   ```
   <?php

               $use_carousel = of_get_option('showhidden_slideroptions');
               if ($use_carousel) {

               ?>

               <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                   <!-- Carousel items -->
                   <div class="carousel-inner">

                       <?php
                       global $post;
                       $tmp_post = $post;
                       $show_posts = of_get_option('slider_options');
                       $args = array( 'numberposts' => $show_posts ); // set this to how many posts you want in the carousel
                       $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                       $post_num = 0;
                       foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
                           $post_num++;
                           $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                           $featured_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'wpbs-featured-carousel' );
                       ?>

                       <div class="<?php if($post_num == 1){ echo 'active'; } ?> item">
                           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured-carousel' ); ?></a>

                           <div class="carousel-caption">

                               <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                               <p>
                                   <?php
                                       $excerpt_length = 100; // length of excerpt to show (in characters)
                                       $the_excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); 
                                       if($the_excerpt != ""){
                                           $the_excerpt = substr( $the_excerpt, 0, $excerpt_length );
                                           echo $the_excerpt . '... ';
                                   ?>
                                   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read more &rsaquo;</a>
                                   <?php } ?>
                               </p>

                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                       <?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>

                   </div>

                   <!-- Carousel nav -->
                   <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                   <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
               </div>

               <?php } // ends the if use carousel statement ?>
   ```

Really appreciate for your help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. How can I make the carousel call a specific category instead of displaying all post inside my wordpress.

Here you are call the carousel initialize using the class not in id like below:

```
$(".class").carousel( { autoSlide: true } );
```

2.You need to click the arrow so that the image slide will work, is there a way to set it to automatically slide? 
I think the carousel is provide a parameter to autoslide like below:

```
$("div").carousel( { autoSlide: true } );
```

Referance site: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm#autoslide

Comment: Hi thank a lot chirag, I use this:http://www.lanexa.net/2012/04/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-display-wordpress-dynamic-content/

everyting is okay now